# Trying to find a counterexample for a false theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to find a counter example for the following theorem:

Suppose there are three functions $h$, $f$, and $g$ that satisfy the following inequalities:
$$ 
h(x) < f(x) < g(x) 
$$
for all $x$ such that $0 < |x - c| < p$ for some $p > 0$, and
\begin{align*}
\lim_{{x \to c}} h(x) &= H, \\
\lim_{{x \to c}} f(x) &= F, \quad \text{and} \\
\lim_{{x \to c}} g(x) &= G,
\end{align*}
for some real numbers $H$, $F$, and $G$. We claim that $H < F < G$.

I have tried everything that I can think of to find a counter example but nothing worked. For instance, if I were to choose $h(x) = 2x$, $f(x) = 4x$, and $g(x) = 6x$, then as $x$ approaches $0$ the claim would be violated, but the conditions would also be violated meaning it is not a counter example.

I have tried piecewise functions as well and ran into a very similar issue where if the claim is violated, then the conditions were also violated and vice versa. I thought of using a Dirichlet function for $f(x)$ so that $f(x)$ would have no limit, but that would also violate the conditions. I am currently at a loss and would appreciate any sort of feedback/advice/input from anyone. Thank you.

By the way, sorry for any possible formatting issues, it is my first time posting here.

Comment: I think you've basically found a counterexample! What about $|2x|$ and $|4x|$ and $|6x|$?

Comment: Even with a strict inequality between functions, we can only guarantee weak inequality between limits.

Comment: @Mark_Parker why would $c=0$ violate the conditions? It actually gives you the counterexample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that can go wrong is that $F$ can equal either $H$ or $G$. If we change the claim to be that $H\leq F\leq G$, then it is actually true. Now a counterexample would be

$$h(x)=0,\quad f(x)=\lvert x\rvert, \quad g(x)=\lvert x\rvert+1$$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, as then

$$h(x)<f(x)<g(x)$$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ (i.e. $0<\lvert x-0\rvert$), but

$$\lim_{x\to0}h(x)=0=\lim_{x\to0}f(x).$$

Comment: Thank you for your timely response. I was wondering, wouldnt it be unacceptable to set h(x) = 0 since 0 is not a function? Are there any possible counter examples without zero?

Comment: @Mark_Parker since when was 0 not a function?

Comment: @Mark_Parker it is a function though. Any constant function is a function

Comment: @Lorago You are right, I dont know why i looked at the number zero and didnt think it would be a constant function. I think I understand where my problem was. I kept looking at c = 0 and thinking that it would violate the conditions since h(0) = f(0) = g(0) so h(0) < f(0) < g(0) must be false, but I seemed to forget that x is approaching 0 and is not actually zero itself. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @Mark_Parker pretty much yes. You even wrote im your question that the inequality only has to hold when $0<\lvert x-c\rvert<p$, and the condition $0<\lvert x-c\rvert$ means that $x\neq c$, so the inequality doesn't have to hold at that point (and indeed the functions don't even need to be defined there as we are only approaching the point as you say)

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Mark_Parker great! Then feel free to accept my answer :)